# How to generate a prepared MySQL query from a variable array?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to merge tables from different schema into one single schema so I would like to execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO inventory.maintenance
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NULL, 'A' as department_id, maintenance.* FROM a_inventory.maintenance
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, 'B' as department_id, maintenance.* FROM b_inventory.maintenance
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, 'E' as department_id, maintenance.* FROM e_inventory.maintenance
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, 'L' as department_id, maintenance.* FROM l_inventory.maintenance
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, 'M' as department_id, maintenance.* FROM m_inventory.maintenance
) AS tmp_maintenance
```

I have to do this query for many different tables and all tables are not in all departments. Instead of writing each queries manually, I would like to add a bit of automation...

```
SET @department = ('A', 'B', 'E', 'L', 'M');
SET @connection = 'inventory';
SET @table = 'maintenance';

/* MAGIC HERE to create @union */

SET @s = CONCAT(
    'INSERT INTO ', @connection, '.', @table,
    'SELECT * FROM (', @union, ') AS tmp');

PREPARE stm1 FROM @s; EXECUTE stm1; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;
```

I would like to create `@union` from `@department`. I have tried to use `REPEAT`, but it does not really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to solve this problem. But you need to have a table `departments` somewhere from which you can extract the `id` assuming the `id` is a `char`:

```
SET @department = 'A,B,E,L,M' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SET @connection = 'inventory';
SET @table = 'maintenance';

SET @union = '';
SELECT @union := CONCAT(
    @union, 
    ' SELECT NULL, "', id , '", ', 
    @table,'.* FROM ', id, '_', 
    @connection, '.', @table, 
    ' UNION '
)
FROM departments WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @department);

SELECT @union := SUBSTRING(@union, 1, LENGTH(@union) - LENGTH('UNION '));

SET @s = CONCAT(
    'INSERT INTO ', @connection, '.', @table, ' '
    '( SELECT * FROM (', @union, ') AS tmp)');

SELECT @s;

PREPARE stm1 FROM @s; EXECUTE stm1; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;
```